# Google Chrome CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-float

I have my code like this

HTML

```
<div class="m"><img src="blue.jpg"></div>
```

CSS

```
.m{ 
  border:0px solid blue; 
  float:left; min-width:65px; 
  padding:23px 4px 10px; 
  text-align:center; 
  color:#8A4C25; 
  font-family:TW Cen MT;
  font-size:15px; 
}
```

Float left is not working in Google Chrome. Is there any solution for this

Comment: Can you give the url of the page? I dont see any reason for Float not working in chrome

Comment: We need to see a bit more code than this. What do you mean it's "not working"?

Comment: `float:left` has worked fine for me in Chrome for many years...can you post the rest of your code, including the elements surrounding `.mod-indent` and their CSS?

Comment: You could make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).  Just put the smallest code sample that shows the problem

Comment: Hello Nate B What do you mean in the sense? Isn't working

Comment: @user1067018, what *is* happening and what do you *want* to happen?

Comment: @user1067018, http://jsfiddle.net/concypt/DEWkW/4/ ... its working perfect in all browsers. you need to give more details so we can see where is the problem

Comment: Hello, Could anyone help me why my account banned and I couldn't ask any questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parent `<li>` you have set its `position:relative;` Please remove it or set its `min-height` to some thing.

```
.path-course-view li.activity{
   margin-right: 20px;
   position: relative;
   min-height:500px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Imran, the same website (http://eabyas.in/FinishingSchool), the Langing Page only I had a problem displaying extra space between header and Menubar in IE7

Comment: @user1067018 please create a new question bro

Comment: Hello, Could anyone help me why my account banned and I couldn't ask any questions ?