# Why doesn't the 'float' property work on IE7?

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer-7

PHP

```
$activities = mysql_query('SELECT icon FROM mdl_activity');
foreach($activities as $a)
{   
  $icon = $a->icon;
  <div class="mod-indent">'.$icon.'</div>
}
```

`$icon` is an image from database.

CSS Code

```
.mod-indent { border:0px solid blue; float:left; min-width:65px; padding:23px 4px 10px; text-align:center; color:#8A4C25; font-family:TW Cen MT;
          font-size:15px; }
```

Why isn't the `float:left` property working in IE 7?

Comment: Might I suggest making your title a bit more specific? It's very vague right now.

Comment: A link to an example page or a http://jsfiddle.net/ would be great.

Comment: Can you put your html/css up on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I'm assuming the PHP you put up there is not the actual code; there's syntax errors and `$activities` is not iterable (it is a MySQL result resource).

Comment: What's your doctype? please post the relevan html

Comment: Didn't you ask this the other day? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478471/google-chrome-css

Comment: I yesterday had a look at your problem (in the link posted by @benni_mac_b) - the float was working OK, but your layout uses a lot of messy relative positioning, and the floated div was hidden behind another element. I suggest you set .mod-indent to position:relative, with a z-index of 9999 - and see if that fixes it.

Comment: If you have a question about some markup + CSS not rendering as you expect in a browser, then show us that markup and CSS, not some PHP. Also, don't reduce your test case to the point where we can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Display: block;` in css code